# How to pass a ref for a component using map()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a card component that's generated with data from a graphql query and map(). I want to be able to add a ref to the last card generated so I can use the InteserctionObserver API to load more cards when the user scrolls to the last card on the screen, how can I pass a ref to the last card?

this is the code I have

```js
const IndexPage = ({ data }) => {

const [currentIndex, setIndex] = useState(3)
const [element, setElement] = useState(null)
console.log("element", element)

 return (
<div className="article-cards">
          {data.allStrapiArticle.nodes
            .slice(0, currentIndex)
            .map((article, index, cards) => {
              return (
                <Card
                  id={article.id}
                  title={article.title}
                  category={article.categories}
                  author={article.author.name}
                  content={article.content}
                  imgUrl={article.cover.publicURL}
                  date={article.created_at}
                  slug={article.slug}
                  ref={index == currentIndex ? setElement : null}
                />
              )
            })}
        </div>
)
```

Comment: use `useRef` hook instead of `useState`, [Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const IndexPage = ({ data }) => {

const [currentIndex, setIndex] = useState(3)
const element = React.useRef(null)

React.useEffect(() => {
console.log("new Element", element.current)
}, [element.current])

 return (
<div className="article-cards">
          {data.allStrapiArticle.nodes
            .slice(0, currentIndex)
            .map((article, index, cards) => {
              return (
                <Card
                  id={article.id}
                  title={article.title}
                  category={article.categories}
                  author={article.author.name}
                  content={article.content}
                  imgUrl={article.cover.publicURL}
                  date={article.created_at}
                  slug={article.slug}
                  ref={index == currentIndex ? element : null}
                />
              )
            })}
        </div>
)
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work, even if I just do ref={element}. Thanks for your help.